# Xamarin Live: "Visualization Error: No body on method System.Void RuntimeCoreNet.GeneratedWrappers.CoreArcGIS..."

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2017, arcgis

Greetings and description of this issue:

(a) Visual Studio 2017 (VS2017) Professional with Xamarin installed on a 64-bit Windows 10 Pro OS computer and the template Xamarin Forms Shared project confirmed working on my test iPhone;

(b) the vsix of ArcGis Net 100.2.0 installed successfully for VS2017, created a new project/solution in VS2017 using the default 'ArcGIS Runtime App(Xamarin.Forms Shared)' template. The generated projects for Android, iOS and UWP compile without any issue within VS2017;

(c) On my test iPhone, I downloaded from the 'App Store' via 'TestFlight' the 'iPhone Player verion 1.4.129 (629)' which is the best version of Xamarin Player available as of January 2018;

I paired the Player with VS2017, saw the start-up iOS project of the solution of (b) above successfully deployed without any further error message in the VS2017, but on my iPhone, I got the following two line of error messages:

'Xamarin Live: Visualization Error: No body on method System.Void RuntimeCoreNet.GeneratedWrappers.CoreArcGIS...'.

Any suggestions on what could be wrong with the default, ArcGIS Net 100.2.0 template solution (without any change) for the iOS project trying to show a default ArcGIS Street Map ? By the way, the default Android project of the same solution runs and shows the map successfully in an Android Emulator. Thank you.

---

The error message becomes the following 2 lines on the test iPhone in XAMARIN LIVE when the a try/catch statement is used:

Visualization Error

ArcGISRuntimeEnvironment.Initialize error: NInterpret.NInterpretException: No body on Method...

after the code changed to:

```
try { ArcGISRuntimeEnvironment.Initialize(); } catch (Exception Ex) { throw new Exception("ArcGISRuntimeEnvironment.Initialize error: " + Ex.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

In case that someone is looking at this issue, the error message is caused by the following line of code in the App.cs of the Xamarin Forms Shared project:

ArcGISRuntimeEnvironment.Initialize();

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to limited features of the iPhonePlayer / Xamarin Live Player which requires to pair to the iOS project in visual studio 2017.

Using a Mac machine as the Xamarin Mac Agent and select the target iPhone (iPhone 7 iOS 11.2 for example) the street map is correctly shown.